# Remove a 'variable' element from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a webshop that has a wishlist function. By clicking a small button next to the products, they get saved in the session, and the products can be viewed on the Wishlist page.

On the Wishlist page, it's possible to click the same kind of button, to remove the product from the wishlist. However, instead of removing the specific product, it removes the first 1/2 products from the list/array.

Here is the current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var x;
var y;

function setPosition() {
    x = jQuery('.navbar-right li.wishlist img').offset().left;
    y = jQuery('.navbar-right li.wishlist img').offset().top;
}

setPosition();

jQuery(window).resize(setPosition);

jQuery('img.add-to-wishist').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var wensenlijst = Cookies.get('wensenlijst');
    if (wensenlijst === null || wensenlijst === "" || wensenlijst === undefined || wensenlijst === "null" ) {
        var temp = [];
        wensenlijst = temp;
    }
    else {
        wensenlijst = JSON.parse(wensenlijst);
    }
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('attr-id');

    if( !jQuery(this).hasClass('done') ) {
        jQuery(this).addClass('done');
        var mysrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        var newsrc = mysrc.replace('likeitem.png', 'liked.png');
        jQuery(this).attr( 'src', newsrc);
        var clone = jQuery(this).clone().addClass('clonedHeart').insertAfter('img.add-to-wishist');
        var eOffset = jQuery(this).offset().top; //get the offset top of the element
        var eLeft = jQuery(this).offset().left;
        var eTop = eOffset - jQuery(window).scrollTop(); //position of the ele w.r.t window
            clone.css('z-index','10000')
                 .css('top', eTop)
                 .css('left', eLeft)
                 .css('position', 'fixed')
                 .animate({
                    left: x,
                    top: y,
                 }, 1500);
                 clone.queue(function() {
                    jQuery(this).remove();
                    var counter = jQuery('#wishlistcount');
                    var currentcount = wensenlijst.length;
                    counter.html( currentcount );
                    counter.addClass('itemAdded');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                      counter.removeClass('itemAdded');}, 2000);
                    jQuery(this).dequeue();
                 });
        wensenlijst.push(id);
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('done');
        var currentcount = jQuery('#wishlistcount').html();
        jQuery('#wishlistcount').html( parseInt(currentcount) - 1 );
        var mysrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        var newsrc = mysrc.replace('liked.png', 'likeitem.png');
        jQuery(this).attr( 'src', newsrc);
        var i = wensenlijst.indexOf(id);
        if (wensenlijst.length === 1) {
            wensenlijst = [];
        }
        else {
            wensenlijst = wensenlijst.splice(i);
        }
        if( jQuery('body').hasClass('page-template-template-wensenlijst') ){
            jQuery.when(Cookies.set('wensenlijst', wensenlijst, { expires: 7 })).done(function() {
                location.reload();
            });
        }
    }
    Cookies.set('wensenlijst', wensenlijst, { expires: 7 });
});});
```

I figured out that the way I spliced the array is wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it right. Most information I have seen were related to a specific thing in an array that needed to be removed, not in a setting where it is variable..

This is a snippet of a button:

```
<div class="save"><a href="#"><img src="image/src" attr-id="4737" class="like-item add-to-wishist" alt="add to wishlist"></a><p>Bewaren</p></div>
```

Comment: can you please just mention the button code??

Comment: Good point. Added it to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second parameter to a slice() function call and remove assignment.

instead of

```
wensenlijst = wensenlijst.splice(i);
```

write just

```
 wensenlijst.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I do this, the new array becomes the product I tried to remove, plus a product next to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer again. This time it only returns the product i tried to remove, nothing else!

Comment: Yep, you need to remove the assignment. The slice() returns the element being deleted. And you need just what's left in the original array.

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks a lot. Looks like that fixed it!